# How do you submit a form, using Selenium, via javascript, from a clicked <div>?

Tags: perl, selenium, selenium-rc

I have a div in an html page like the following:

```
<div id="save_one" onclick="save_one()" >Save Contact Info</div>
```

save_one() gets all the form data in a form below and saves using an ajax call.

Clicking the div ought to save the contents, and it does using a mouse, but I've 
been unable to get it to work with Selenium.

The page has an

```
<img onclick='edit_table()'>
```

that when clicked opens the table 
to be edited as a form.  I'm able to do that with selenium. I'm also able to 
update the form with new data using Selenium.

When attempting to submit it using the div shown above it fails unless I extract the
script from the .js file and run it with Selenium using:

```
$sel->get_eval( $js_save_one );   # $js_save_one is the js sub in a string in the perl 
                                  # test file
```

Is it the case that selenium only handles certain Javascript functionality?  If that is 
not the case, anyone know why this would not operate as it does using the mouse?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the Selenium firefox extension, it can create the code for whatever language you are using to run selenium through and it will tell you how to do this.  Basically though there is a function for clicking a button/image.

Comment: Selenium has had issues with javscripting this kind of stuff, try to identify the form element in the html if you can.

Comment: Well, if it does, then I might be in trouble. Also I think that one of the problems might be that in this case there is no form to submit.  It's just not good html. The table turns into input forms but they're just used be the js. There isn't a form. I'm aware of the functionality for clicking buttons and images, submitting forms and the like. I'm just having problems clicking divs that initiate ajax call. I'll check out the FF plugin. Thanks.

Comment: I personally was never able to make any of the js functions triiger and/or work using the selenium framework and the selenium server (jar file), when i tried to research it becuase they did say they supported it, i found nothing on it other than other people complaining about JS not working.  The FF plug in though did make dev so much easier in my projects, i would then take the output code and put into my own projects that controlled the testing

Answer (score 0):

Since the element has an `id` attribute, it should be as easy as:

$sel->click( 'id=save_one' );

Or perhaps:

```
$sel->mouse_down( 'id=save_one' );
$sel->mouse_up( 'id=save_one' );
```

Either one should launch the JavaScript action in the browser.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not having any trouble getting those to work. Thanks.